# A ring extension of $\mathbb Z$ in which $x^4+y^4+1$ is reducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

My first instinct was the ring of two variable polynomials modulo $a^4+b^4+1$.($\mathbb Z[a,b]/(a^4+b^4+1)$)
But I haven’t managed to reduce it to linear factors.
Can any of you help?

Comment: $x^4+y^4+1$ looks like a polynomial. Do you mean the polynomial ring $\Bbb Z[x,y]$?

Comment: I’ve just renamed the variables for conviniance.

Comment: So what is $x^4+y^4+1$ then? A polynomial?

Comment: A polynomial over $\mathbb Z[a,b]/(a^4+b^4+1)$ I’m trying to reduce.

Comment: $x^4+y^4+1$ is of course zero in the quotient. Do you want to show that $x^4+y^4+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x,y]$? I don't understand the question. You cannot factor it into linear factors, except over $\Bbb C$, of course.

Comment: I don’t mean $a^4+b^4+1$ the *element* of the ring, I mean $x^4 +y^4+1$ the *polynomial* over the ring(for which $x=a,y=b$ is a solution). I probably wasn’t clear enough in the question.

Comment: Have you thought about possible factorizations? I think you need zero divisors in your ring extension to achieve that. But the ring you wrote down is an integral domain.

Comment: Why would zéro divisors be necessary?

Comment: $\mathbb Z[a,b]/(a^4+b^4+1)$ sits inside $\mathbb Q(b)[a]/(a^4+b^4+1)$, which is a field extension of $\mathbb Q(b)$, since $x^4+b^4+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q(b)[x]$. A possible factorization would provide a 2nd or 4th root of $b^4+1$, which doesn't exist in $\mathbb Q(b)$.

Comment: I wish strongly that you had stated the question in the body. It’s not fair to the folks who may be helping you to give the statement only in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. From the title, it looks as if you’re looking for a ring $A$ containing $\Bbb Z$ such that the polynomial $x^4+y^4+1\in\Bbb Z[x,y]$ becomes reducible when viewed as a polynomial in $A[x,y]$.

Perhaps you were thinking of your question as an analog to the one-variable situation, where the $\Bbb Z$-polynomial $x^4+1$ becomes reducible, first over the Gaussian numbers, where it’s $(x^2-i)(x^2+i)$, and better over the ring gotten by adjoining a primitive eighth root of unity $\zeta=\zeta_8=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$, as $x^4+1=(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^7)(x-\zeta^3)(x-\zeta^5)$.

Now, lamentably, if you’re restricting your rings $A$ to subrings of the complex numbers, $x^4+y^4+1$ remains irreducible no matter what $A$ is. The reason is that as soon as you get into multivariable polynomials, you’re suddenly no longer doing basic number theory nor abstract algebra, but Algebraic Geometry.

Geometrically, one thinks of $x^4+y^4+1=0$ as describing a “curve” in the (affine) plane over the complex numbers; topologically it’s a surface. And if you look at it in the way you should, as a curve in the projective plane over $\Bbb C$, it becomes a compact Riemann surface, of genus three. It’s only when, as a curve, it consists of two (possibly intersecting) curves in the plane that the original polynomial would have been reducible.

Since the algebraic geometers’ curve, topologists’ Riemann surface, defined by your polynomial equation $x^4+y^4+1=0$, does not break up into two separate, perhaps intersecting, curves/surfaces, your polynomial is “absolutely irreducible”, never becomes reducible no matter what field you consider its coefficients to lie in.

Answer (score 1):

Homogenize and reduce to: is $P(x,y,z)=x^4 + y^4 + z^4$ reducible in $K[x,y,z]$, for some ring $K\supset \mathbb{Z}$?  If it is, then some (easy to write) system of equations with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ has a solution in $K$. But that means ( [Hilbert nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz)) that the system has a solution in $\mathbb{C}$ ( or even in
$\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$).

So assume that $P(x,y,z) = P_1(x,y,z)\cdot P_2(x,y,z)$, with $P_1$, $P_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, homogenous, of positive degree, and $\deg P_1 + \deg P_2 = 4$.

The complex projective curves $P_1=0$, and $P_2=0$ have a non-void intersection ( [Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem#Plane_curves) implies this). Let $(x_0\colon y_0\colon z_0)$ a common point of these curves, that is $P_i(x_0, y_0, z_0)=0$.
But this implies with the product rule
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}(x_0, y_0, z_0) = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}(x_0, y_0, z_0)=\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}(x_0, y_0, z_0)=0$$
(a singular point of the curve $P(x,y,z) = 0$).
But this implies $x_0 = y_0 = z_0 = 0$, contradiction. ( a point in the projective plane has at least one of the projective coordinates $\ne 0$).

Note: This works for any $P$ homogenous of $3$ variables for which the curve $P=0$ is non-singular.

For comparison, the polynomial $x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4 - z^4$ is reducible. It also has two singular points: (at infinity) $(1\colon \pm i\colon 0)$.

Comment: I like this answer a lot. Thanks, plus one.